# Listbox For statement not looping through listboxs

Tags: c#, listbox

4th time asking this question after trying to apply so fixes. My problem is I have 2 listboxs one holds IDs and the other holds Cell ids. The ID listbox has 10 items (for testing) and Cell boxes have 5 ID. I'm trying to process listId and listCell at the same time creating update links...

example **MakeReq** will create **txtWebUpdate.Text listID listCell &ire=1**, in which is

```
        store.domain.com/101/sec01&ire=1
        store.domain.com/102/sec02&ire=1
        store.domain.com/103/sec03&ire=1
        store.domain.com/104/sec04&ire=1
        store.domain.com/105/sec05&ire=1
        store.domain.com/106/sec01&ire=1 <- notice how listCell starts over it 
continues to loop applying sections until the ListID is complete.
```

here's the code i've been working with. what's happening with my code is that it's only selecting the first item. It's not going to the next item after its done.

```
        if (listId.Items.Count != 0 && listCell.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < listId.Items.Count; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < listCell.Items.Count; b++)
                {
                    lblID.Text = listId.Items[a].ToString();
                    MakeReq(txtWebUpdate.Text + listId.Items[a].ToString() + 
                        "&ire=1", listCell.Items[b].ToString());
                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
                }
            }
        }
```

Please only comment if you can help. I'm almost positive that the problem is the for statement and how it's selecting list items, but I may be wrong.

**Edit More Info:** after testing an example/suggestion for @duffp below the problem is definitely with my For statements. What's happening is its counting that I have 5 entries in ListCell and then output one (the same) ListID 5times but with a different ListCell. Can someone help me write it following what I wrong above?

Comment: Is your updating of the listbox triggering a postback, making you step out of the loop?

Comment: @kcsavage yes. I use to do something like this in vb6 a while back, with vb I would use the Remove property to take out the item after each process. So it would always be grabbing the first item. But in this case I'm working with two Listbox one of which listCell can't have items removed from it cause it needs to continuous loop providing SecID's for each ListID

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do within the MakeReq method call.  I just tried the following code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (listId.Items.Count != 0 && listCell.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < listId.Items.Count; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < listCell.Items.Count; b++)
                {
                    lblID.Text = listId.Items[a].ToString();
                    MakeReq(listId.Items[a].ToString(), listCell.Items[b].ToString());

                }
            }
        }            
    }
    public void MakeReq(string listId, string cellId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("store.domain.com/" + listId + "sec01&ire=" + cellId);
    }
```

And it gave the output:

```
store.domain.com/ID_10sec01&ire=Cell_1
store.domain.com/ID_10sec01&ire=Cell_2
store.domain.com/ID_10sec01&ire=Cell_3
store.domain.com/ID_10sec01&ire=Cell_4
store.domain.com/ID_10sec01&ire=Cell_5
store.domain.com/ID_10sec01&ire=Cell_6
store.domain.com/ID_10sec01&ire=Cell_7
store.domain.com/ID_10sec01&ire=Cell_8
store.domain.com/ID_10sec01&ire=Cell_9
store.domain.com/ID_10sec01&ire=Cell_10
```

Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: store.domain.com/ID_01 sec 01 &ire=1
store.domain.com/ListID + ListCell ... ex: /01sec01&ire=1 once once ListCell reaches its end it starts over /11sec01&ire=1. all listCell is doing is applying sections in a loop while ListID process one time straight through from top to bottom

Comment: where you have ID_10 those IDs are always different. look at my output example up top store.domain.com/101/sec01&ire=1 101 is ListID sec01 is listCell ... and notice what happens when ListID gets to 106, it ListCell starts over, why because ListCell only has 5 entries. so it continues to apply secIDs (listCell) even if it has to start over until listID box is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some side-effects in MakeReq that you are not showing us. How about adding some debug statements to your code, like this:

```
    if (listId.Items.Count != 0 && listCell.Items.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < listId.Items.Count; a++)
        {
            int listCellCount = listCell.Items.Count;
            for (int b = 0; b < listCell.Items.Count; b++)
            {
                lblID.Text = listId.Items[a].ToString();
                MakeReq(txtWebUpdate.Text + listId.Items[a].ToString() + 
                    "&ire=1", listCell.Items[b].ToString());
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
                Debug.Assert(listCellCount == listCell.Items.Count);
            }
        }
    }
```

The assertion (listCellCount == listCell.Items.Count) should always be true, unless something is changing listCell.Items.

Comment: I used a console.write as @duffp did in his example. And I have another problem that I didn't notice. It's not MakeReq() during the console.write output i'm getting the same ListID printing out 10 times per process. so my For statement is all wrong. The reason I say its not MakeReq because its not doing anything other than holding the strings. If I used labels instead I would get the same result not outputting the correct info.